# absolute position bottom:0 does not work as expected in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position

I have a table, which is put inside a div. And this table has 4 td elements and inside each td element, there are 3 div stacked from top to bottom. My goal is to make the third div positioned at the bottom of the table. CSS below:

```
tr {
  height: 220px;
}

td {
  position: relative;
}

third-div {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute:
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

[html image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjXuS.png)

it works fine in firefox and chrome but bottom:0 in IE11 does not work correctly, I got a text overlay issue:(the number in the third div, which is 2000, is not set at the bottom of the table)
[html rendered in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZEPX.png)

what is expected is:
[html rendered in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J878n.png)

I tried to set the height to auto/100%, did not work. I manually clicked bottom:0 in developer tool, it worked, 2000 went to the bottom. (not sure why).

Comment: Please add HTML sample code in order to test. make sure that the height of td is set to 100% and bottom: 0 !important to 3rd-div

Answer (score 0):

The class name of the `div` in html is `third-div`, but you use `3rd-div` in CSS and lack of a selector for the style rule. I made a demo like below and it can work well in both IE 11 and Chrome:

```css
tr {
  height: 220px;
}

td {
  position: relative;
}

.third-div {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-xs-3"></td>
      <td class="col-xs-3"></td>
      <td class="col-xs-3">
        <div>Amount Financed</div>
        <div>The amount of credit provided to you.</div>
        <div class="third-div">
          <span id="amount">$10,000</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-xs-3"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: that was just a typo. I typed this whole css manually through developer tool, it worked. But If I changed my local css file and rendered the html in IE, it did not work. I am not sure why

Comment: It seems that the css file hasn't been applied correctly in IE. Have you used media query or specific css targets browsers except IE? Have you used F12 dev tools to check if the css style applied to the element correctly? Could you please provide a sample which can reproduce the issue?